# How to detect when drag input is end in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I don't know how to detect when the user drag event is end or not so I decide to do like this

```
protected class Input extends DragListener{
    boolean dragging=false;

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        if(!dragging)dragging=true;
            *my game logic*
            .
            .
            .
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("touch up","");
        if (dragging) {
            *my game logic*
            .
            .
            .
        }

    }
}
```

I try my class by drag and touch up ,nothing happen.
I drag again and nothing happen. then I tap and the console is print "touchUp" two time.
Is there anything else to detect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface `GestureListener` that resides in `GestureDetector` there is a method `pan` and `panStop`. You should implement that interface, add all the methods from it and use `pan` for your dragging behaviour and `panStop` for the solution to your question. The methods register for both touch and mouse as well as multiple finger touches.

Comment: Is there an EventListener class that contain panStop.I must extends an EventListener to addListener to Actor

Comment: No, just implement `GestureListener` and use the method. If you want you can call your own method from that or set a boolean to use.

Comment: but I want to receive event that with actor by use addListener(EventListener listener) if it does't EventListener then how can  I use it

Comment: I really don't know what you are asking just implement `GestureListenerer ` on your actor class. `class MyActor extends Actor implements GestureListener`. Create the interface methods and whenever you stop panning the `panStop()` method is called.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation and english skill.
What I understand is if I implements GestureListener like you tell I must set it as input processor (Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()) .The pan() methode will call every time I pan no matter if is inside or outside actor but  I want to call pan() only when I drag from inside my actor like drag and drop

Comment: Then you need another statement within `panStop()`. Setup a boolean `isWithinActor` and use that inside the `panStop()`. `if (isWithinActor) { do stuff }. You can also write your own listener but that is a whole different kind of question, but I really think you should just use what LibGDX is offering.